# Why are my Django passwords not being encrypted?

Tags: django

I'm using Django, and I added the views to create, update, etc. my users. I'm using the users from`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, and I can successfully see the `auth_user` created when migrating.

The only issue I see is that the passwords are not being hashed. I have another project, in which I can see the passwords being automatically hashed, and as far as I could investigate, that's the default behavior they should have when using the default Django users, correct? I'm relatively new to Django, so this is probably something quite simple.

My create view looks like this:

```
class UserCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """
               -----------------------Vista de crear usuarios--------------------------
    """
    template_name = 'users/users_form.html'
    model = User
    fields = ["username", "password", "is_superuser", "is_staff", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_active"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("users:list_users")
```

Another thing (that's less of an issue, but maybe it's relevant information) is that the password field is in the view not appearing as a password field per se, but as a regular text field.

Any help would be grately appreciated.

Comment: Because nowhere you specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only issue I see is that the passwords are not being hashed.

Because nowhere you specify that. You can override the `form_valid` method. If you make use of the [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) then this automatically hashes the password, and also uses two password fields that look if the passwords match, and present the passwords as a password field.

You can thus hash it by overriding [**`form_valid(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid):

```
class UserCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/users_form.html'
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff',
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_active'
    ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:list_users')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        super().form_valid(form)
```

or we can make use of a `UserCreationForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/users_form.html'
    model = User
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:list_users')
```

You can include extra fields by overriding the form and define extra fields:

```
# app/forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'first_name', 'last_name',
            'email', 'is_active'
        )
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}
```

and then use this form in your view:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class UserCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/users_form.html'
    model = User
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:list_users')
```

It might however not be a good idea to include `is_superuser` fields, since this can result in a [*privilege escalation* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) where a normal user can create an admin user (here you only restrict it to logged in users), and thus eventually obtains more privileges.